# Read/Write Struct Containing Arrays to/from Binary File

Tags: struct, fwrite, fread

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct codeKey_s {
    unsigned char shortest;
    unsigned char longest;
    unsigned char lengths[256];
    int table[256];
} codeKey_t;
```

As you can see I have statically sized arrays of value types. My problem is when I save, and then read them from a binary file both of the arrays are empty. I see other people making this work with char* strings, so what gives?

Here are my write/read statements:

```
fwrite(codeKey, sizeof (codeKey_t), 1, file);

codeKey_t* retCodeKey = (codeKey_t*)malloc(sizeof(codeKey_t));
fread(retCodeKey, sizeof(codeKey_t*), 1, readFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

From TFM

```
On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written.
```

You're only trying once to fread and fwrite; it's not guaranted they finish in one call.

The other question is the timing - do you open and fread the file shortly after the fwrite, maybe before closing the write filehandle? If so, you may need to flush the write filehandle, before reading.

**Update**
You're calling fread wrong

```
fread(retCodeKey, sizeof(codeKey_t*), 1, readFile);
```

passing the size of a pointer type into the `size` argument.

Comment: Ah yes, my file handling was correct with closing and opening. I was reading in the size of a pointer, that was the problem. Thank you!